# Do we have a simpler way to find all the positive integers satisfying $2^{n-1}|n!$?

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, factorial

For any integer $n$, let $n! = 2^kd$ for some non-negative integer $k$ and odd integer $d$.

For any power of $2$ , i.e. $n=2^h$, where $h$ is non-negative integer.
$$
\begin{aligned}
k & =\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{2^2}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{n}{2^{h-1}}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{2^h}\right]\\
& =2^{h-1}+2^{h-2}+\cdots+1 \\
& =2^h-1 \\
& =n-1
\end{aligned}
$$
$\therefore 2^{n-1} | n !$ for any $n=2^h$.

---

We now deal with **odd** integers $n>1$.
Noting that $[\frac{n}{2^r}] =[\frac{n-1}{2^r}]$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}k & =\left[\frac{n}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{2^2}\right]+\left[\frac{n}{2^3}\right]+\cdots \\& =\left[\frac{n-1}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{n-1}{2^2}\right]+\cdots\\ &<(n-1)\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\cdots\right)\\&=n-1 \cdots (*)\end{aligned} \tag*{} $$

Therefore $k<n-1$ and hence $2^{n-1}\not|n!$ for any **odd** integer $n$.

---

Now for any **even** integer $n$ which is not a power of $2$, we let $n=2^he$ for some positive integer $h\geq 1$ and odd integer  $e\geq 3$. Then

$$\displaystyle \begin{aligned}k & =\left[\frac{2^h e}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{2^h e}{2^2}\right]+\cdots+\left[\frac{2^h e}{2^h}\right]+\left[\frac{e}{2}\right]+\left[\frac{e}{2^2}\right]+\cdots \\\\ & < (2^{h-1} e+2^{h-2} e+\cdots+e)+(e-1) \quad \textrm{ (Using (*))} \\& =\frac{e\left(2^h-1\right)}{2-1}+e-1\\&=2^h e-1\\&=n-1\end{aligned}\tag*{} $$

Therefore $k<n-1$ again and hence $2^{n-1}\not|n!$ for any even integer $n$ which is **not** a power of $2$.

---

We may now conclude that $n=2^h$ are the positive integers satisfying $2^{n-1}|n!,$ where $h$ are non-negative integer.

Do we have a **simpler** way to find all the positive integers satisfying $2^{n-1}|n!$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3282967/78967

Comment: You want the "alternate form" of Legendre's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula#Alternate_form

Comment: This is about as simple as it can be. Well done.

Comment: Let $f_n$ denote the maximum $k$ such that $2^k|n!$ so $f_{2n+i}=n+f_n$ for $i\in\{0,\,1\}$. We can now prove by induction on the number of binary digits of $n$ that $f_n=n-1$ iff all but the leftmost of them is $0$. Is that simpler, in your opinion? (Working with $g_n:=f_n+1$ might be even simpler.)